# How to convert String on restful service to xml file for xsd validations

Tags: java, xml, json, web-services, rest

Updated question

I have modified my client code and restful service code as

updated cliet code is

```
URL url = new URL("http://localhost:9090/XsdValidation/api/data/xml");
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/xml");

        ////


        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader("Employee.xml");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
        for (String line = reader.readLine(); line != null; line = reader.readLine()) {
            builder .append(line);
        }
        String xml = builder .toString();
        System.out.println("xml file is "+xml);
        OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
        out.write(xml);
        out.close();
        reader.close();
```

updated rest ful service code is

```
@Path("/data")
public class DataAccess {
    @POST
    @Path("/xml")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public String readXml(String file) {

        System.out.println("in xml");
        return file;
    }

}
```

everything was fine the string i was getting is `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><empns:employee xmlns:empns="Symplocus/Employee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="Symplocus/Employee Employee.xsd ">  <empns:EMP_ID>0101</empns:EMP_ID>  <empns:NAME>Rajasekhar</empns:NAME>  <empns:SALARY>2000</empns:SALARY>  <empns:DATEOFJOINING>2001-01-01</empns:DATEOFJOINING></empns:employee>`

i want to convert this whole string to an xml file in order to do validations with xsd .. can any one have an idea to convert string to XML file

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

////this was the asked previously i got answer for this from GAgarwarl's post///
I was updating the question,now i was able to send xml file to rest ful service,how to read this read this xml on restful service

my client code is

```
URL url = new URL("http://localhost:9090/XsdValidation/api/data/xml");
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/xml");

    OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream();

    TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer = tf.newTransformer();
    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader("Employee.xml");
    StreamSource source = new StreamSource(fileReader);
    StreamResult result = new StreamResult(os);
    transformer.transform(source, result);

    os.flush();

    System.out.println(connection.getResponseCode());
    //connection.disconnect();
     BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
     System.out.println("in input stream");
     String decodedString;
     while ((decodedString = in.readLine()) != null) {
     System.out.println(decodedString);
     }
     in.close(); 
     System.out.println(connection.getResponseCode());

    System.out.println("end of client programme");
```

and my restful code is

```
@Path("/data")
public class DataAccess {
    @POST
    @Path("/xml")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public String readXml(/here i have to read file /) {
             // here i want an idea to read the file sent by client

    }

}
```

////this was old question////

I was completely new to web services,I have to send an XML file in system location like `c:/Files/Samle.xml` from java client to Restful web service,Previously i have send json object to restful but unable to send xml

my client code to send json is

```
String tableName="SYMPLOCUS.IMDB1_FINANCE_BUDGE ";

        String urlString="http://localhost:9090/DataAccess/api/DataAccess/loadData?tableName="+tableName;

        URL url=new URL(urlString);
        HttpURLConnection httpCon = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        httpCon.setDoOutput(true);
        httpCon.setRequestMethod("POST");
        httpCon.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", 
                "application/json");

        OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(httpCon.getOutputStream());
        String json = "{\"EMPCODE\":\"125\", \"NAME_TBH\":\"aaaaa\"}";
        out.write(json);
        out.close();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpCon.getInputStream()));
        System.out.println("in input stream");
        String decodedString;
        while ((decodedString = in.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(decodedString);
        }
        in.close(); 
        System.out.println(httpCon.getResponseCode());
```

and my restful code is

```
@Path("/loadData")
        @POST
        @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        public String sendReceiveJson(String data,@QueryParam("tableName") String tableName) 

        {
}
```

in the same way i wand to send xml file to restful service , can some one have any ideas..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace 
 String json = "{\"EMPCODE\":\"125\", \"NAME_TBH\":\"aaaaa\"}";
With:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
FileReader fileReader = new FileReader("fileName");
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
for (String line = reader.readLine(); line != null; line = reader.readLine()) {
    builder .append(line);
}
String xml = builder .toString();
```

Comment: ok thank you,now how to again convert this to file in restful web service...                              public String sendReceiveJson(String xml )                                                                { // code to convert string to xml file }

Comment: this works really great ... now the whole xml is  going to restful service as string it's perfect.. do you have any idea of how to convert this string again to xml... so that i can do xsd validations

Comment: DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder;
   try
    {
  builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document document = builder.parse( new InputSource(
                    new StringReader( xmlString ) ) );
 
            TransformerFactory tranFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Transformer aTransformer = tranFactory.newTransformer();
            Source src = new DOMSource( document );
            Result dest = new StreamResult( new File( "name.xml" ) );
            aTransformer.transform( src, dest );

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
@consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON,MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
```

And also in your client side set:

```
httpCon.setRequestProperty("content-type","application/xml")
```

And then send your `XML` data.

Comment: that' fine,thank you.. but my question is how to add the file to the post in client ...like any methods ...

Comment: may i know how to consume xml at rest full service

Comment: u mean to say  like this String json = "{\"EMPCODE\":\"125\", \"NAME_TBH\":\"aaaaa\"}";
        out.write(json);

Comment: sorry i have just given old code for reference ,actually i have to send an xml file to restful service and have to read that file in service.. @Sacreties

Comment: @consumes("application/xml") public Response getXML(Employee emp) should be in your service and then read and send ur <Employee><empid></empid></employee> to the service. may i know which jax-rs implementation you are using? jersey,restful,etc...

Comment: GAgarwal answer worked to send xml to restful as string ..i want to do xsd validations for thet so do you have any idea to convert the string to xml ...something like marshalling.. @ Sacreties J